# CSS force page to be a minimum of 100%

Tags: css

This is driving my crazy and I just cant get it to work how I want (I have tried searching forums but can't find a way to fix my code). I want the layout of my page to be 100% of the window height.

<strike>The JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/JvPc2/3/embedded/result/ to display the issue</strike>

**Update:** The JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/JvPc2/4/embedded/result/ to display the issue

The HTML for one page is as follows:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="headcontainer" >
            <div id="headerleft">
                <h1>
                    Bringing Them Home
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div id="headerright">
                <h2>
                    Tagline to go here?
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div id="splitbar"></div>
            <div id="navleft">
                    <a href="/"><span class="outer"><span>Home</span></span></a><a href="the30.php"><span class="outer"><span>The 30</span></span></a><a href="thehall.php"><span class="outer"><span>Memorial Hall</span></span></a><a href="research.php"><span class="outer"><span>Research Page</span></span></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navright">
                    <a href="about.php"><span class="outer"><span>About</span></span></a><a href="tour.php"><span class="outer"><span>Virtual Tour</span></span></a><a href="schools.php"><span class="outer"><span>School Work</span></span></a><a href="links.php"><span class="outer"><span>Links</span></span></a>
            </div>
            <div id="splitbar"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="maincontainer" >
            <div id="maincontentleft">
                <p>
                    On this page you will find some relevant links to find out more information:
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a href="/">Bringing Them Home site</a><br />
                    <a href="/">Bringing Them Home site</a><br />
                    <a href="/">Bringing Them Home site</a><br />
                    <a href="/">Bringing Them Home site</a><br />
                    <a href="/">Bringing Them Home site</a><br />
                    <a href="/">Bringing Them Home site</a><br />
                </p>    
            </div>
            <div id="maincontentright" >
                <p>
                    <a href="/">Bringing Them Home site</a><br />
                    <a href="/">Bringing Them Home site</a><br />
                    <a href="/">Bringing Them Home site</a><br />
                    <a href="/">Bringing Them Home site</a><br />
                    <a href="/">Bringing Them Home site</a><br />
                    <a href="/">Bringing Them Home site</a><br />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footercontainer">
        <div id="splitbar">
        </div>
            <div id="footerleft">
                <p>
                    &copy;Stefan Wright Web Design 2014
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="footerright">
                <p>
                    Contact the webmaster <a href="mailto:webmaster@bringingthemhome.co.uk">here</a>.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS is below:

```
html{min-height:100%;position:relative}
body{background-image:url('../images/bg_leather.png');margin:0px;height:100%}
#wrapper{height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;}
#adminoverlay{z-index:10;width:100%;background:whitesmoke;position:relative;top:0;}
#adminoverlay p{margin:0px}
#headcontainer{width:100%;min-width:697px;height:20%;font-family:'MyUnderwood'}
#headerleft,#headerright{margin-bottom: 0px;text-align: center;background-image: url('../images/bg_content_rep.png');background-size: cover;width:48%;height:50%;min-height:62px;float:left;margin-left:1%}
#headerright h2{line-height: 2em;-webkit-margin-before: 0.80em;-webkit-margin-after: 0.80em;}
#navleft,#navright{width:48%;min-width:320px;height:40%;min-height:50px;margin-left:1%;float:left;font-family:'MyUnderwood';background-image: url('../images/bg_content_rep.png');background-size: cover;}
#navleft a,#navright a{float: left;text-align: center;width: 21%;padding-left:2%;padding-right:2%;max-width: 131px;height:100%;font-size: 19px;color: black;}
#splitbar{background-image: url('../images/bg_content_top.png');background-size: cover;background-position: center top;height: 10%;width:100%;float: left;min-width:320px}
#maincontainer{width:100%;min-width:697px;min-height:68%;min-height:250px;clear:both}
#maincontentleft,#maincontentright{width:42%;min-width:320px;height:100%;margin-left: 1%;padding-left: 3%;padding-right:3%;float: left;font-size: 14px;font-family: 'MyUnderwood';background-image: url('../images/bg_content_rep.png');background-repeat: repeat-y;background-position: left top;background-size: 100%;}
#footercontainer{width:100%;min-width:697px;height:10%;min-height:50px;clear:both}
#footerleft,#footerright{width:42%;min-width:320px;height:90%;margin-left:1%;float:left;font-family:'MyUnderwood';background-image: url('../images/bg_content_rep.png');background-size: cover;padding-left:3%;padding-right: 3%;}
```

Edit: Removed the site URL's and included the JSFiddle.

Comment: Your site requires a password :/ Please provide a fiddle

Comment: oh my apologies. I have removed it now, I meant to do that before posting

Comment: Ok now it works, but please provide a fiddle for future visitors anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the problem, on both sites content dosn't fill the whole vertical screen space, at least on a Full HD screen.

Comment: @veritas I guess it must just be my resolution, so either way its not what I want. I am trying not to create a fiddle im not too sure what i'm doing on jsfiddle to be honest (sorry)

Comment: It looks like you basically had what you wanted at one point.. The min-height of #maincontainer was set to be 68%, which looks to me like it does exactly what you want.. But it's currently being overridden by a min-height of 250px. Is there something wrong with using the percentage min-height that you had?

Comment: Hi @BlakeMann I have updated this on http://jsfiddle.net/JvPc2/4/embedded/result/ but if you notice the background doesnt continue to fill. Perhaps I did almost have it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more tinkering I got this working by moving the maincontentleft and maincontentright divs out of a container div. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

**Lazy solution**

Not to loose your precious time i would suggest to go for a JS solution, which would be simply fetch parent's height and substract all containers except content.

**Other solutions**

- Consider changing the element which holds the background
- Use flex boxing model (when targeting newest browsers)
- When you don't care about keeping exact footer and header heights you could go for percentage height for all elements.

Comment: Thanks I don't think I want to go down a JS solution I would like to keep this to just CSS. I have set percentages on all the elements I thought (correct me if I am wrong). How could I change the element holding the background?